# How to stop a script in skulpt

Tags: javascript, python, promise, skulpt

I made a skulpt project for my students. Every time they made an infinite loop, the browser crashes and the code is gone. That is very frustrating for the students. I saw a stop button on https://trinket.io/python, but don't understand how they made it. 
I followed the instructions on http://www.skulpt.org/ to integrate skulpt in my site.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/jsbin/loop-protect

Comment: If the student asks a user for an input, it will be canceled, because the user is not fast enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not particularly well documented - there are certain options that you can add to the `Sk.configure` one of which is `execLimit` in ms.

e.g. From the example http://skulpt.org/using.html

```
Sk.configure({output:outf, read:builtinRead, execLimit: 5000});
```

Skulpt will raise a `TimeLimitError` if the `execLimit` is reached.

---

in terms of the cancel button - there's an additional setting `yieldLimit` which you can set in `ms`. This will essentially pause the execution at intervals. And you can add a handler to deal with this pause.

Again not documented well by Skulpt but here's a JS Fiddle that is proof of concept:

https://jsfiddle.net/bjLuq5s7/

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! This solved my problem and two others, too.